# displaying result of HTML form on with js function

Tags: php, javascript, html

I know that you cannot really have variables in html, but I'm wondering if this is possible. I have searched around and cannot find anything that clearly answers my question. Hopefully someone hear can point me in the right direction. Here's what I have in mind:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" name="test">
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(test)">
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(test)
{
alert("Welcome " + test);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Would this work or something like it? 
Thanks, Sam

Comment: What *precisely* are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: To answer your question, no, that would not work, as `test` doesn't have any value.

Comment: to alert the value of the text input, sorry for being unclear

Comment: javascript can grab the values of inputs from the document. [Read up on how to do this.](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-get-form.phtml)

Answer (score 3):

If you mean using the contents of an input as a variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" id="some_id" name="test">
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(document.getElementById('some_id').value)">
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(test)
{
alert("Welcome " + test);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is you want to access `<input>` and send it to `function(test)`
try this:

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test"> <-- Give ID here
<input type="submit" onclick="myFunction(test)"> <--Send same ID here
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(test)
{
alert("Welcome " + test.value);
}
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: don't you want to pass `document.getElementById('test')` to `myFunction()`?

Comment: @Matt the question was unclear, as I have said I have answered what I understood from question. I thought the guy wanted to send `test` as parameter to his method to get it's value.